# Extjs 4 save state of a checkboxGroup when parent window is closed

Tags: javascript, extjs4, javascript-framework

I have a window with a checkboxGroup in it. I would like whatever selections are made in the checkboxGroup to be saved when my "apply" button on the window is pressed. So far I have

```
                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                    stateful: true,
                    stateID: 'checks',
                    getState: function() {
                            return {
                                    items: this.items
                            };
                    },
                    stateEvents: ['close'],
                    columns: 2,
                    vertical: false,
                    items: [...]
```

I'm pretty sure my stateEvents are wrong, what would I use  to indicate that I want the state to be saved when the parent window is closed?

I have this line in my app.js file's launch function, right before I create the top viewport

```
            Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

apparently the state of the checkbox group does not include the values of the checkboxes http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup-method-getState

i had to go via a session variable and the parent window events ..

```
var configPopup;
var configForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    id: 'form-config',
    name: 'form-config',
    frame: true,
    layout: 'anchor',
    items: [
      {
        border:0,
        anchor: "100%",
        xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
        fieldLabel: 'Include options',
        labelWidth: 100,
        id: 'opt_relation',
        labelStyle: 'margin-left:10px;',
        items: [
          {         
        boxLabel: 'relation 1',
        name: 'opt_relation',
        inputValue: 'rel1',
        checked: true
      },
      {
        boxLabel: 'relation 2',
        name: 'opt_relation',
        inputValue: 'rel2',
        checked: true
      },
      {
        boxLabel: 'relation 3',
        name: 'opt_relation',
        inputValue: 'rel3',
        checked: true
       }
     ]
   }        
    ],
buttons: [
      {
      text: 'Close',
    handler: function() {
      configPopup.hide();
    }

  }]
});


configPopup = new Ext.Window({
  id:'configPopup',
  title: 'Chart configuration',
  layout      : 'fit',
  width       : 390,
  closeAction :'hide',
  plain       : true,
  listeners: {
    show: function() { 
      var v = Ext.state.Manager.get("optRelation");
      if (v) {        
        Ext.getCmp('opt_relation').setValue(v);
      } 
    },
    hide: function() { 
      var v = Ext.getCmp('opt_relation').getValue();      
      Ext.state.Manager.set("optRelation",v); 
    }
  },
  items : [ 
    configForm
  ]
});
```

Comment: thank you! I ended up designing my app a different way but can anyone confirm that this method works?